# Unable to download distribution package for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, proxy

I'm currently testing with a django web application using version 1.6 with a python version 3.4.1 and needs to install some packages here on my machine. Based from what I've observed we are currently connected to a proxy server which is why I'm having issues downloading some of it. Below are the actions that I've taken so far.

1) I've updated my http_proxy connection to `http://innoproxy:8083/proxy.pac` which is our current proxy connection.

2) Below is error that mostly occurs when I would install the South Package.

```
C:\Users\fx0.MANDAUE>pip install South
Downloading/unpacking South
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement South
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for South
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\fx0.MANDAUE\pip\pip.log
```

My question is, would it be possible for me to install that package without using the command prompt(manual download) or do I still lack some actions from my end for the downloading to work? I've already checked other possible solutions but so far to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: I think this link is what you need: [South Installation using mercurial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#using-mercurial). On this page you have explanations about how to install it with _pip_ or _easy_install_ and also via file with _Mercurial_

Comment: @Liarez done installing using mercurial but still it gives me `abort: error:Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in a similar situation behind my corporate proxy. You may first want to check whether your proxy is looking for authentication, in which case setting you connection string to `http://username:password@proxyserver:port/` may help. In my case, however, our authentication relies on Windows Active Directory, which I've yet to overcome on my Linux box.

If all else fails, as in my case, you can manually download the source `tar.bz` (or similar compressed directory) from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and use `pip install path/to/source`. This will mean manually downloading all dependencies and installing them the same way. It can be a pain, but it works.

Comment: installing them manually seems the only option left from my end. thanks!